# Getting command not properly ended while testing for empty relations

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am reading database systems concepts book by Henry Korth.I tried the following exactly from the book for empty relations test.

```
select course_id
from section as S
where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009 and 
exists (select *
        from section as T
        where semester = 'Spring' and year = 2010 and
        S.course_id = T.course_id);
```

However, I am getting command not properly ended error on the second line.Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you using to run statements against the DB? Perhaps SQL\*Plus? The error message tells you exactly where the error is (what line of code and the exact character). In most cases you can use that to find out exactly where the error is. Then you can read the documentation. This is how you will identify many errors in the book. (By the way, it is also absolutely OK to ask here - but learning to read and understand error messages, and to read the documentation to understand them, is very helpful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `AS` in table alias, it's for column alias.

Rewrite you query removing `AS`.

```
select course_id
from section  S
where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009 and 
exists (select *
        from section T
        where semester = 'Spring' and year = 2010 and
        S.course_id = T.course_id);
```

Comment: I wonder why they don't correct it in the book.But thank you.